# Validate ISO8601 start_time is before ISO8601 end_time in elixir/ecto/timex

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm working on json request using phoenix where I have start_time and end_time in ISO8601 format and I want to validate that end_time is > start_time, so given:

```
 {
    "start_time": "2016-07-07T01:00:00+02:00",
    "end_time": "2016-07-07T01:30:00+01:00"
 }
```

validation error should be returned for both fields saying that "start_time": "must be less then end_time" and "end_time": "must be greater than start_time".

What is preferred way to accomplish that using ecto changesets (+ timex)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your custom `vadlidate_time_range` function and use it inside pipeline in `changeset` function. Those validators need to take `changeset` structure as first argument and return `changeset` structure.

Inside this function you need to check both dates. If they changed, they will be in `changeset.changes`. If not, you will need to extract them from model. You can get them like this:

```
start_time = changeset.changes |> Dict.get(:start_time, nil)
start_time = start_time || (changeset.model |> Dict.get(:start_time))
{:ok, start_time} = Timex.parse start_time, "{ISO:Extended}"
```

The same goes with end time, so you might want to extract those three operations into a function.

Then you need to compare with `Timex.Comparable.compare(start_time, end_time)`.

```
case comparison_result do
  1 ->
    changeset
  _ ->
    changeset
    |> add_error(:start_time, "must be less then end_time")
    |> add_error(:end_time, "must be greater than start_time")
end
```

Comment: I've ended up using Calendar but this one was good guideline. Thanks @tkowal